# Firebase keeps changing JSON file

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Firebase database my JSON tree is setup like this (notice the "0" and "1")

```
{
  "0" : {
    "Coordinates" : {
      "Lat" : -29.00902,
      "Long" : 31.98
    }
  },
  "1" : {
    "Coordinates" : {
      "Lat" : -28.8,
      "Long" : 30.00007
    }
  },
  "num" : 1
}
```

For the first few times I download the JSON file it downloads as it is above and everything is fine but then for some reason it changes to this after a few downloads, it takes out the "0" and "1" (but in my Firebase console nothing has changed, it still shows that it's part of "0" or "1").

```
 {
            "Coordinates" : {
              "Lat" : -29.00902,
              "Long" : 31.98
            }
          },
          {
            "Coordinates" : {
              "Lat" : -29.775252,
              "Long" : 31.021821
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is cause because of how JSON works, and how Firebase displays JSON on their website. Because you are using keys like `0` and `1`, firebase thinks that you are trying to create an array (maybe you are). Firebase displays this like your first example, but when you export it to a JSON file, instead of showing the `0` and `1`, it uses the standard square brackets `[]` around the data to imply an array. This is NOT a bug, but firebase displaying the JSON in a way that is much easier for humans to view, and exporting the data in the more computer readable format. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ahh I see. Well when when I download that part I do use it in an array hence the way it’s numbered. I only have it like that instead of a list cause it’s easier to view. They should have a way to turn off/on this feature or at least more info about it cause it does that for some parts of my database but not others.

Answer (score 0):

That is the way Firebase works, it is no bug. It is not guarenteed you download the data in order as it is ordered in the console. You can get the number of the json’s parent by called ‘key’ on your downloaded data. Off-topic: i would not recommend ordering your data like that.

Comment: This happens when I export the JSON file from the console